# How can I query all records with timestamp older than 30 days using cURL?

Tags: linux, curl, solr

I want to fetch all records (from Solr) with a timestamp older than 30 days via cURL command.

What I have tried:

```
curl -g "http://localhost:8983/solr/input_records/select?q=timestamp:[* TO NOW/DAY-30DAYS]"
```

I do not understand why this does not work but it does not fetch anything. It simply returns nothing. If I replace '[* TO NOW/DAY-30DAYS]' with an actual value, it will retrieve that record.

Additional relevant information, this is how to delete all records older than 30 days (it works). Again, I do not want to delete, rather just fetch the data.

```
curl -g "http://localhost:8983/solr/input_records/update?commit=true" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary "<delete><query>timestamp:[* TO NOW/DAY-30DAYS]</query></delete>"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening because you don't have proper [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for your request. Most likely the problem is spaces - need to replace them with `%20`, same applies to other symbols

Try this:

```
curl -g "http://localhost:8983/solr/input_records/select?q=timestamp:[*%20TO%20NOW/DAY-30DAYS]
```

Answer (score 0):

A further addition to Mysterion's answer,

Since you are doing this using curl, you are facing the issue of the URL encoding.

If you just mention
`http://localhost:8983/solr/input_records/select?q=timestamp:[* TO NOW/DAY-30DAYS]` 
in your browser (chrome or others)
the Url encoding is automatically handled by the browser and you would get your response as expected.